# Moving Microsoft Powerpoint 2007 files to usb

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I am trying to attach all my files used in a presentation with the `.ppt` file so I can get it working on a different PC. I tried to follow [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_8494181_transfer-powerpoint-files-flash-drive.html) tutorial which said that I should click on File option, but there is no file option in ***PowerPoint 2007***. Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The instructions say "*click the "Office Button" in PowerPoint 2007*". That's the big round button in the corner. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I did. There is no save and send button in that menu.

Comment: Ah yes, the instructions seem to be for PowerPoint 2010. In PowerPoint 2007, select Publish, the "Package for CD" option is under that.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. You can post it as an answer and I will mark it. Else, I would have to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerPoint 2007, to get the "Package for CD" option, click the round Office button in the top left corner and look under **Publish**.

[image]